# using variable of the foreach loop outside foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop, and i create a string inside the loop, but I want to use the var outside the loop, is it possible?

```
    List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();
    foreach(var rolenodes in roleIntList){          
     string myStr = "hello";
    }
```

Comment: Suggest going over this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: The variable declared inside the parenthesis called "roleIntList" is intended to be used only to iterate values inside the List. It depends on what you want to do with the values, so I'll replicate the previous question, why do you need that variable outside?

Comment: This looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can if you declare the string outside the loop:

```
string myStr = null;
List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();
foreach(var rolenodes in roleIntList){          
    myStr = "hello";
}
```

Then, after the loop runs, `myStr` will contain the last-assigned value.

Comment: After I run the loop, use myStr again outside the loop, the value of myStr is null or "hello"?

Comment: Try it out.  I'd expect "hello".

Comment: It wouldn't be `"hello"`, it will be `null`, since the enumerator is empty.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, you have a good point.  I'm assuming the OP gave us an abridged version of the code and that, in reality, the list is populated.

Comment: @adv12 The question isn't making too much sense TBH, not sure what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: The scope of a variable is the code block where it is declared. Declare it before the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitively not possible, it's also not a good idea to declare the variable "inside" the foreach loop, why don't you consider this:

```
List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();
string myStr;
foreach(var rolenodes in roleIntList){          
   myStr = "hello";
}

...

//use myStr
```

Answer (score 0):

for each (type **identifier** in expression) {
   statements
}

**Note:  the identifier in the above case
The iteration variable that represents the collection element. When identifier is a Tracking Reference Operator (C++ Component Extensions), you can modify the element.**
its out of scope the moment for each loop is executed completely

Comment: That link pertains to C++, not C#

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> myStr = new List<string>();
            List<int> roleIntList = new List<int>();

            roleIntList.Add(1);
            roleIntList.Add(2);
            roleIntList.Add(3);
            roleIntList.Add(4);

            foreach (var rolenodes in roleIntList)
            {
                string ss = rolenodes.ToString();
                myStr.Add(ss);
            }

            foreach (string s in myStr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.Read();


        }
    }
}
```